# Stop https and ServerName redirection apache2

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, https, lamp

my issue is simple I want to access http://tunisie-telegraph.com but it redirects me to https://tunisietelegraph.com

my domain name dns are ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com
I have 2 "A" and 2 "AAAA" records (with www and without)

I've deleted the .htaccess file

my virtual host file:

```
# Added to mitigate CVE-2017-8295 vulnerability
UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin private@gmail.com

        ServerName tunisie-telegraph.com
        ServerAlias www.tunisie-telegraph.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The redirect is still active but it is not caused by the config you show. It is unknown what else causes the redirect since this is the only information you provide. Also note that a permanent redirect (301) is served. This is cached by the clients so they might try access 
 the redirect target directly even after you've fixed the problem on the server side.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i'm using digitalocean wordpress prebuit droplet, tunisietelegraph.com was the domain I've used first and it worked fine with https, but now I want to switch to the new domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please check Site URL & Home URL in wp_options table. Might be URL is different over there in one of the column because when i have added the url like this https://tunisietelegraph.com/wp-login.php it's not redirecting

Or you can set the Site URL & Home URL from wp_config.php as well

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://tunisie-telegraph.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://tunisie-telegraph.com' );
```